Adjusting the table row height - Row height in different on different URLs
I was trying to adjust the height of table rows/cells and I actually managed to on my test page, but the problem persists on the original one. The files are ALL the same (I actually deleted everything from root folder and uploaded stuff from test folder), but the cell height doesn't change although - when I view the page on the test URL, it's perfect.
Original page on http://something.com/
Test page on http://something.com/test
Table properties:
<style type="text/css"> 
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;} 
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px; overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;} 
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px; font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;} 
.tg .tg-dtlu{background-color:#f8ff00;border-color:#000000;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:top} 
.tg .tg-etfl{background-color:#ffffff;border-color:#000000;color:#000000;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; vertical-align:top} 
.tg .tg-pmvn{background-color:#f8ff00;border-color:#000000;color:#000000;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; vertical-align:top} 
.tg .tg-f2xw{background-color:#efefef;border-color:#000000;color:#000000;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; vertical-align:top}

I tried to clear browser cache, I tried purging server-side cache (via this script), I used header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); on top of index.php.
I tried viewing the site with a remote browser that checks website as they would be seen on other devices, but the problem is there also.
I think it's still a cache problem - probably server-side, but how to solve this?
If anybody has any idea, please let me know.
